# How to replace WebDriverWait() with lambda expression?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, lambda, java-8

I want to know how to replace popular `WebDriverWait` with lambda.

It is used for explicitly wait some event.

***Code snippet:***

```
(new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver.get(), 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(By.id("DataTables_Table_0_processing")).isDisplayed();
    }
});
```

Or:

```
(new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver.get(), 10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions
                .invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("DataTables_Table_0_processing")));
```

***How to replace it with lambda expression?***

Comment: If you're doing this in IDE, every decent modern IDE have a quick-fix or refactoring like "convert anonymous class to lambda expression". Just hit it, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver.get(), 10))
        .until(d -> d.findElement(By.id("DataTables_Table_0_processing")).isDisplayed());
```

I don't think the second case would be improved with a lambda since there's already a convenience method which provides sufficient clarity.

Comment: What should we use instead of WebDriverWait in Selenium 4.2 and above?